# How to properly resolve conflict during azure synchronization from android?

Tags: android, azure

I'm in trouble with azure synchronization, I'm able to detect the number of pending operations by `mCLient.getSyncContext().getPendingOperations();` but can't resolve them. Any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with in an offline scenario and you have pending operations, you can push them to the server by using the `push()` function.

It would look something like the following:

```
try {
    MobileServiceSyncContext syncContext = mClient.getSyncContext();
    syncContext.push().get();

    // here you would do a pull on any table you want to grab data from
}
catch (final MobileServiceConflictException e)
{
    // the server item causing the exception can be obtained by calling e.getItem()
    JsonObject serverObject = e.getItem();

    // on the sync context, call one of the following:

    // .cancelAndDiscardItem() to cancel update and discard local item

    // .cancelAndUpdateItem() to update the local item with the server's copy

    // .cancelAndUpdateItem(JsonObject item) to update the server's item w/ the local

    // make sure to call push() again on the sync context
}
```

All in all - make sure you call `push()` on the `MobileServiceSyncContext` and then handle any `MobileServiceConflictException` that may return.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my mistake was that I was looking for the item in other type of Exception.

Answer (score 0):

If I catch for MobileServiceConflictException android studio tells me that the Exception is never thrown in this corresponding try block.

```
try {
                        MobileServiceSyncContext syncContext = mClient.getSyncContext();
                        syncContext.push().get();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (MobileServiceConflictException e) {

                    }
```

Comment: For me too, android studio does not allow adding this catch.